# How to set PYTHONPATH to a project directory?

Tags: python, module, python-module

I am trying to import a module from a different directory:

`from preprocess.utils import get_image`
But this is the error that I get:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'preprocess'`

I tried editing the `.batch_profile`, and setting the PYTHONPATH as follows but it still doesn't fix the error:

`export PYTHONPATH="/Users/username/documents/project_directory/"`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: How do you run your program, and from which directory? And where is `preprocess` directory in relation to it?

Comment: @Amadan I run the program from the root directory like so `python preprocess/filename.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python automatically adds the project directory to the module load path (`sys.path`). However, depending on how you run the file, the which directory is picked is different. When you run `python preprocess/filename.py`, the directory added to the load path is the directory that the script is in: `preprocess`. If you execute the program as a module, run it as `python -m preprocess.filename`, the current working directory is the one added to the load path, and your code should work.

If you want to execute your script using `python preprocess/filename.py` syntax, the easiest fix is to move `filename.py` to the project root directory, or to make a wrapper script that will reside in the root and import `preprocess.filename`.

`export PYTHONPATH="/Users/username/documents/project_directory/"` should also work, but it is not really great; what if you start working on a different project? That aside, putting it into `.bash_profile` should work though, as long as you have made sure it was actually executed. On OSX, it is executed automatically when you open a new Terminal. On most other flavours of UN*X, it is executed only when you log in. If you have made changes to `.bash_profile`, they won't take effect until you trigger the above (new Terminal or re-login), or you explicitly execute them using `source ~/.bash_profile`.

You can check which directory was auto-added to the load path by executing the following as the first line in your `preprocess/filename.py`:

```
import sys; print(sys.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use windows and I also could not get changing "PYTHONPATH" to work predictably.

In your case, you can do something like

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"path_that_you_want")
```

Depending on your version of python, you may need to put an `__init__.py` file in that directory and all subdirectories. Blank `__init__.py` files are fine.

Please note that for syntax highlighting in some code editors you will need to include that path in the code editor config. (e.g. settings.json in VSCode)